# General concept of dealing with filter combinations

Tags: php, combinatorics

I'm working on a project that uses filters to build a movielist.

[image]

The general idea is, that each filter can be applied on its own.

As you can see in the above picture you can either search for the (title | director | actor) on it own. Or search for movies that run less X minutes. Or search for movies from a certain year.

OR perform a combination of 2 or all of the options.

Currently the project is written in PHP, but I'll take any hints since I'm interested in the general concept of dealing with combinations.

This is my approach so far: I wrote code for all possible combinations of those 3 filters. I'm sure it is the worst of all possible approaches and I hope you could provide me with some insights.

```
if (!empty($suchstring) && empty($dauer) && empty($jahr)) {
    // do for suchstring
}
elseif(!empty($dauer) && empty($suchstring) && empty($jahr)) {
    // do for dauer
}
elseif(!empty($jahr) && empty($suchstring) && empty($dauer)) {
    // do for jahr
}
elseif (!empty($suchstring) && !empty($dauer) && empty($jahr)) {
    // do for dauer THEN do for suchstring
}
elseif (!empty($suchstring) && !empty($jahr) && empty($dauer)) {
    // do for jahr THEN do for suchstring
}
elseif(empty($suchstring) && !empty($dauer) && !empty($jahr)) {
    // do for dauer THEN do for jahr
}
elseif (!empty($suchstring) && !empty($dauer) && !empty($jahr)) {
    // do for dauer THEn do for jahr THEN do for suchstring
}
```

Comment: How are you interacting with your database? Mysqli? PDO? something else?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
    $link = mysqli_connect(SERVER, USER, PASS, DB);

    $sql_str = "SELECT .... ";

   if (!empty($suchstring)) {
      $suchstring = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $suchstring); //or mysql_real_escape_string
      $sql_str .= " AND SUCHSTRING ='".$suchstring."'";  //or LIKE '%".$suchstring."%'
   }
   if (!empty($dauer)) {
      $dauer = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $dauer);
      $sql_str .= " AND DAUER ='".$dauer."'";
   }
   if (!empty($jahr)) {
      $jahr = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $jahr);
      $sql_str .= " AND JAHR ='".$jahr."'";
   }

  //sql_query for $sql_str
```

Comment: The first `AND` may break the query.  NO ONE should be recommending the deprecated/removed `mysql_` functions.  A prepared statement is most appropriate/modern/professional.  Also  your question is missing its plain English explanation.